# Classic ASP and Separation of Concerns

Tags: asp-classic, separation-of-concerns

How far down the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) route can we go with Classic ASP?

Presently, I try to minimise the use of Classic ASP in my mark-up pages by using `Include`s and only embedding (`<%= %>`) `Response.Writes` in output attributes or inner HTML text (e.g. `<input type="text"><%= myVal %></input>`).

On rare occasions it does become necessary to use conditional statements to branch output, but I usually embed this as a call to a `Sub` defined in the included ASP code.

That is where things become a little more crazy, though. I'm interested in seeing how others separate their mark-up when coding up a section of a form, or group of HTML controls, within a Classic ASP code file.

As a simple example, let's say we have a function that simply displays a label and a text box on a form when the sub `InputPair` is called from the mark-up:

```vbs
<% InputPair "Forename", dsFormItem(C_COL_FORENAME, 0) %>
```

The sub behind the call then needs to display the appropriate HTML mark-up elements, obviously a `label` and `input (type=text)` box. I have seen this done several ways, including:

- `Response.Write()`
- Nested HTML
- Separated HTML lniked via `include`

<strike>But how would you, the reader, go about applying SoC in such circumstances? This is a two way road, after all; personally I find it poor practice to include HTML mark-up in strings.</strike> To make this a more appropriate question for S.O: What is best practice for SoC when using Classic ASP?

Comment: Not sure you can. I've tried so many times to achieve SoC with Classic ASP but the layers always bleed into one another. The closest I have seen is the [ASP Xtreme Evolution](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution) framework. But to be honest if you are going to go to that extent switch to ASP.Net-MVC and save yourself some pain.

Comment: we need to learn let go some things with time. and move forward with new ones

Comment: @Lankymart: I know what you mean, but MVC isn't an option for me in some cases. Don't get me wrong - I don't use Classic ASP all the time, but when I have to, I like to try and make it as easy to understand as possible, and separate out the mark-up, JavaScript and VBScript. Must admit, I've never seen ASP Xtreme Evolution before.

Comment: @ddw147: If I could mark your comment down I would. It's not always possible to do what you'd like to do.

Comment: @Paul it not about what we like to do. its about what we can do

Comment: That's fair enough, to be honest just structure your pages more like end points to keep thing's neat a pattern I use often is all my pages tend that require lots of interaction always begin with an `Sub init()` and that is always the only procedure that is called then all the logic is broken down into various functions/procedures. It's not SoC but it's an attempt at structuring the code. To be honest though Classic ASP is so versatile and no one way is the right way.

Comment: @Lankymart: I've considered doing this, but I tend to follow an open initialisation followed by closed functions that are called by the page, and, if I'm honest, avoid classing everything up...